# zooming map in QGIS map canvas without changing the scale

Tags: qgis, mapcanvas

I use QGIS to create maps mainly for printing in scale 1:100.000 to 1:25.000. It would be great, if the map in the canvas could be zoomed without changing the scale of the canvas.
The only way to get "into" the map is to change the scale. But I want to enlarge my view like with a magnifying glass. (I know, I could use magnifying glass from operating system, but I'm looking for a QGIS-Canvas solution)

Is there already a way? Is it worth to place a feature-request? Is anyone else interested in that?

Comment: If you design symbol and labels in map units rather than mm/pixels, the map would behave in the way you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is now available in QGIS 2.16: http://qgis.org/fr/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/index.html#feature-map-canvas-magnifier